# How do I create a Twitter hashtag?

Tags: twitter

I've looked around the internet for a step by step guide on how to create, and define hash tags.

Can someone guide me on how to figure it out?

Comment: Anybody can create a #hashtag; just include it in your tweet. As for defining, that's up to the community. I've seen hashtags that were meant for one thing but which the community decided were for something else.

Comment: Do you just use the words in the text to create a new one?

Comment: Yes. Just remember that you can't have spaces. Back in the dim and distant past, Twitter didn't do anything with hashtags. They just became a convention. It's only fairly recently that Twitter made them "special" by adding search and measuring trends.

Comment: Aww, thanks, I thought there was a special setup to do first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [HELP CENTER](https://support.twitter.com/articles/49309):

> The # symbol, called a hashtag, is used to mark keywords or topics in a Tweet. It was created organically by Twitter users as a way to categorize messages.

Using hashtags to categorize Tweets by keyword:

> - People use the hashtag symbol # before a relevant keyword or phrase (no spaces) in their Tweet to categorize those Tweets and help them show more easily in Twitter Search.
> - Clicking on a hashtagged word in any message shows you all other Tweets marked with that keyword.
> - Hashtags can occur anywhere in the Tweet – at the beginning, middle, or end.
> - Hashtagged words that become very popular are often Trending Topics.

Comment: But how do you create new ones?

Comment: @3.14159265358... #NewHashtag or #New_Hashtag. Do not use whitespace.